# Want to implement mail function in laravel 5.5 in controller

Tags: php, email, laravel-5.5

I want to create a mail function in controller.
For this, Firstly I have run the command, for generating mailables:-

```
php artisan make:mail SpecialOffers
```

Secondly, on SpecialOffers mail file being created by running above command, i included following code in the file under build() function i.e.

```
return $this->from('salon@email.com')
                ->view('emails/emails_special_orders');
```

Now, I have no clue that where should i call mail function and what should i write in route for sending mail.

Comment: check this https://www.5balloons.info/laravel-send-email-example/